# Suggestion for DateTimepicker for asp.net 2.0

Tags: datetimepicker

Anyone can suggest for DateTimepicker for asp.net. I have used GMDateTimepicker.But now in website i cant find the dll.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can see the following example and use it for your own I hope it will be useful to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DateTimePicker.aspx

http://essentialobjects.com/Products/EOWeb/Calendar.aspx